# "vue-router.mjs:3441 TypeError: l.then is not a function" how can I fix this issue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I am working on a training program. I coded the frontend of this training program with vue 3. I started getting errors below build in my code that was working fine on localhost. I would appreciate it if you could help me correct these errors.

Console:
[Console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjQh1.png)

Router.js:

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import HomeView from "../views/HomeView.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: HomeView,
  },
  ...
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "dashboard",
    component: () => require("../views/DashboardView.vue"),
    children: [...]
  }
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

package.json:

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "@formkit/auto-animate": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@kyvg/vue3-notification": "^2.4.1",
    "axios": "^1.1.2",
    "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
    "maska": "^1.5.0",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-axios": "^3.4.1",
    "vue-chartjs": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check your imports in router file. In my case, I got extra callback in `import: ()=> SalesView` you should omit it:

```
import SalesView from "@/pages/sales";

export const router: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: "/sales",
    name: "sales",
    component: SalesView,
    meta: { requiresAuth: true },
 },
];
```